# Enviar $(this) con valor del input a otra función en jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas estoy iterando unos resultados obtenidos a través de una consulta por AJAX. Con `append` muestro los resultado en la pantalla, pero necesito enviar lo siguiente.

**Esto está en el success de un ajax**

```
$('#zonaProductos').append('<div class="lasCat seleccionProducto center" >\
       <div class="addPrueba" data-id="'+ productos[i].id +'">\
          <img src="'+ productos[i].foto +'" alt="" class="img-fluid">\
          <h2>'+ productos[i].name +'</h2>\
          </div>\
          <input class="form-control" type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" value="1">\
        </div>');  
                                                      
        $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner();
```

**Luego tengo una función que obtengo el id del producto que pulso**

```
$('#zonaProductos').on( 'click', '.addPrueba', function(){
    var idProducto = $(this).data("id"); //Aquí obtengo el id del producto que pulso
    var cantidad = $("input[name=cantidad]").val(); //Aquí intento obtener el valor que tiene el input cantidad del producto que pulso
   ......
   .......

});
```

Pero no me funciona, me traer el valor de cantidad siempre del primero que pulso, como lo puedo hacer, lo he intentado así `$(this).val("input[name=cantidad]");` pero tampoco me funciona.

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Conviene incluir siempre en la pregunta un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable para poder probar el código. Estás hablando de *iterar*, por lo que se supone que en la parte del `append` (1er bloque de código) se podrían estar creando varios elementos... si es así ya hay un error ahí y es que estarías asignando el mismo `id`  a más de un elemento, lo cual no es correcto. Dicho eso, en la pregunta no queda claro el contexto en que se encuentran los elementos, lo cual podría ser fundamental para una buena respuesta en casos como estos, pues la selección podrían hacerse según la ubicación del elemento.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano en lo que repito `id` te refieres en el input no? No se como crear un ejemplo para que se pueda probar ya que saco los registros desde la BD y soy bastante nob en JavaScript :S

Comment: Me refiero a esto: `<input class="form-control" type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" value="1">`  si este código ocurre en un bucle o se ejecuta varias veces, estarías creando un elemento con el mismo id varias veces, lo cual es incorrecto. Cuando luego quieras alcanzar ese elemento por su id nunca se sabrá a cual alcanzará, así que los id deben ser únicos. En cuanto a mostrar un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable es tan simple como abrir el código fuente en el navegador y poner en la pregunta una parte de los elementos que se generen (HTML) y el Javascript respectivo, así vemos el contexto.

Comment: Ok si lo que me imaginaba aunque no estaba utilizando ese id, voy a ver como puedo mostrar un ejemplo gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seria también así

```
var idProducto = $(this).attr("data-id");
var cantidad = $(this).next("input[name=cantidad]").val();

/* Mira la salida en consola para saber si son los datos que necesitas */
console.log( idProducto );
console.log( cantidad );
```

El otro problema es que cuando se le da click el evento se dispara en el input directamente y no en el padre class .addPrueba, ahí podrías entonces cambiar de disparador de eventos en lugar de para el padre para el hijo, si me das mas información podría ayudarte mas, infórmame por favor si te funcionó.

Comment: Hola @NelsonR.Graña me devuelve un `undefined`

Comment: Edite, no es el método children() no había visto el cierre de carro del div por tanto input no es el hijo de .addPrueba, es un hermano y en su lugar se usa next()

Comment: Ahora funciona perfecto @NelsonR.Graña muchisimas gracias!